# query not working as intended

Tags: sql, database, oracle, procedure

We have these tables:

```
player(id,salary,bonus)

productivity_per_year(id,goals,year)
```

> Productivity Table (ID,Goals, Year)

```
+----+-------+------+
| ID | Goals | Year |
+----+-------+------+
| 01 |    20 | 2001 |
| 01 |    30 | 2002 |
| 02 |    30 | 2001 |
| 02 |    40 | 2002 |
+----+-------+------+
```

The question is, how can I raise the bonus of a player if the player the last two years (2001 and 2002) strike 30 or more goals. For example here I want the bonus to be take by the player with id=02 since he scored >=30 for both 2001 and 2002 .

I am using the following procedure, but it fails since it adds bonus to both players!!!

```
create or replace 
procedure football
AS
BEGIN
   update player p
      set p.bonus = p.bonus + 500
   where p.id in 
         (select s.id from productivity s where
            s.goals >30 
        and  s.year>=2001
        and s.id = p.id
         );
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both players get a bigger bonus as both players scored more than 30 goals since 2001. This is what you are doing with your query. However, to give the bonus only to a player who scored more than 30 goals in 2001 and 2002 you can try following query.

```
update player p 
set bonus = bonus + 500 
where p.id in 
((select s.id from productivity s where s.goals > 30 and s.year = 2001 and s.id = p.id)
intersect
(select s.id from productivity s where s.goals > 30 and s.year = 2002 and s.id = p.id));
```

With postgresql it works.